# Create a InDateRange validator

Tags: java, validation, date, bean-validation

I'm trying create a InDateRange annotation to validate Date fields that should be between two date, the min date is fixed and the max date should be the current date.

I'm looking this site: http://sterl.org/2015/06/java-jsr-validation-for-dates/ , but I don't know how to turn the max date as the current date. I think that the current date we should pass as parameter, but I don't know how to do this.

Is there a validator for this problem?

Comment: In the isValid() method from the page you’re linking to, can’t you just put `final Date max = new Date();`? This will set max to the current date and time.